# Django: Pass arguments from other form to submit button

Tags: python, html, django, forms, django-templates

I'm building a simple Django app that lets users track stuff for specific days:

[image: form]

It records entries with a name and a date using the upper form.

```html
<form action="" method="post" style="margin-bottom: 1cm;">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.entry_name.label_tag }}
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{ form.entry_name.id_for_label }}" name="{{ form.entry_name.html_name }}" aria-label="new entry field">
                {{ form.entry_date }}

                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <small id="{{ form.entry_name.id_for_label }}Help" class="form-text text-muted">This can be anything you want to track: An activity, food, how you slept, stress level, etc.</small>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Below the form, there are quick add buttons that let users quickly add a new entry with a specific name. In addition, I'd like to use the date selected in the form above. I.e., if a user sets a date in the upper form but then clicks one of the suggested buttons, it should still use the selected date for adding the new entry.

This is what the code for the suggested buttons currently looks like:

```html
{% if entry_counts and entry_dict|length > 0 %}
    <div class="card" style="margin-bottom: 1cm;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card-title">Suggested entries</div>
            {% for name, count in entry_counts.items %}
                <form method="post" action="{% url 'app:add_entry_with_date' name form.entry_date.value %}" style="display: inline-block;">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" name="{{ name }}" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">{{ name }}</button>
                </form>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
```

I'm trying to access the selected date and pass it to the corresponding view: `action="{% url 'app:add_entry_with_date' name form.entry_date.value %}"`, but it still adds the entry at the default date (today) not on the selected date.
My guess, is that the problem is with `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" name="{{ name }}" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">{{ name }}</button>`. Does this just pass `name` but not the date when submitting?

Here are the relevant URL patterns:

```py
class DateConverter:
    regex = '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'

    def to_python(self, value):
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d')

    def to_url(self, value):
        return value


register_converter(DateConverter, 'yyyymmdd')


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('add/<entry_name>/', views.add_entry, name='add'),
    path('add/<entry_name>/<yyyymmdd:entry_date>/', views.add_entry, name='add_entry_with_date'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

So whenever adding a new entry (with or without specific date), my `add_entry` view is called:

```py
@login_required
def add_entry(request, entry_name, entry_date=datetime.date.today()):
    # only works for post
    # if request.method == 'POST':
    entry_name = entry_name.strip().lower()
    entry = Entry.objects.create(name=entry_name, date=entry_date, owner=request.user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:index'))
```

Comment: You're trying to pass the date value through the URL right? “Does this just pass name but not the date when submitting?” seems like an irrelevant question to the problem. The submit button as far as I know isn't supposed to be used for passing data, and you don't have any `input` elements in that form. Anyway, I have a hunch that the problem is in your view rather than your HTML, so it might be helpful if you share the details for `add_entry_with_date`.

Comment: I don't have input elements because I want users to be able to just click a button without having to fill in a text field and date field. Or could I do some kind of invisible inputs where I set the values? Besides, passing the entry name via the button works.
I just updated the description to add my URLs and view as you suggested. Yes, I'm trying to pass the date through the URL for the quick add buttons. I tested the URL with postman and it should work.

Comment: You can definitely make invisible inputs: just use `type="hidden"`. In fact, Django renders `csrf_token` this way. Anyway, I posted an answer, let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to pass the date value as part of the URL,

```
{% url 'app:add_entry_with_date' name form.entry_date.value %}
```

however, `form.entry_date.value` won't have a defined value unless your form is bound before it's passed to the template for rendering. As a result, probably, your `add_entry` view is being called via the URL pattern `add`, not `add_entry_with_date`.

Another challenge with your current code is that you want to have the same date-type `input` element (`{{ form.entry_date }}`) serve as the source for different, separate HTML forms (you have the first form for adding entries, and then you have one form for each suggested entry). Changing the value of that input when the page is already rendered in the browser won't update the `action` URLs for the suggested entry `form`s—unless you use JavaScript.

I think the quickest way to make your existing code work is to write some JavaScript to manipulate the `action` attribute for the suggested-entry `form`s whenever the date input value changes.

Manipulating `action` attributes looks strange though, and also I believe your view, which should work only for POST requests, should use only POST data and not rely on URL parameters. Therefore I recommend that you use hidden `input`s, e.g.

```html
<input type="hidden" name="variable-name" value="temporary-date-value-here">
```

and then have the JavaScript manipulate these `input` elements' values instead of the form `action` attribute. Of course you have to update the view too.

#### Update: sample JS for synchronizing inputs across forms

HTML:

```html
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Sample synchronization of inputs across forms</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Sample synchronization of inputs across forms</h1>

        <h2>Form 1</h2>
        <form>
            <input class="synchronized-inputs" type="date" name="input_date">
        </form>

        <h2>Form 2</h2>
        <form>
            <input class="synchronized-inputs" type="date" name="input_date">
        </form>

        <script src="sync-inputs-across-forms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </body>
    
</html>
```

JavaScript (`sync-inputs-across-forms.js`):

```js
var syncedInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('synchronized-inputs');

Array.from(syncedInputs).forEach((source) => {
    source.addEventListener('change', () => {
        Array.from(syncedInputs).forEach((target) => {
            target.value = source.value;
        });
    });
});
```

Note that:

- Without the JS, selecting a date in one form won't update the other form's value
- As indicated in the original answer, you'd want to use hidden inputs for the suggested-entry forms. To do that, just change `type="date"` to `type="hidden"` for the other form. Synchronization will still work as the value is tracked in the (invisible parts of the) DOM.

Comment: Do you have an example of what the necessary JavaScript could look like? When/how should I call it? Basically, whenever a user selects a date in the main/upper form, right? Then it should copy the value to the invisible input of the suggested entries. Not sure how to do this best with JS.

Comment: @CGFoX I updated the answer with sample JS. You 'call' it by just declaring event listeners—it's the JavaScript way, you react to browser events such as user clicks. Yes, the script would copy over the value of the main/upper form's date widget to the invisible inputs when a user manipulates the main form's widget.

Comment: How do I get the initial value for the hidden dates? I just noticed that it doesn't work before I actively select the date in the date selector. I figured out how to copy the default from the date selector on window load using JS, but shouldn't this also be possible in Django?

Comment: @CGFoX set a `value` attribute inside the `input` tags to initialize their value. If you want to do it server-side, yes, with Django you can add `value="{% now "Y-m-d" %}"` to initialize with the current date. You can also of course do this client-side, with JS.